# PDO SQL not going into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am tring to get data from a form to go into my SQL database using PDO this same code has been working for me until now. The code does post to this page but I don't know what I am doing wrong or has changed to get it not to go into database. I got the insert code from phpMyAdmin

> INSERT INTO `car-subclass-desc`(`sub-model-id`, `car-model`, `sub-model-name`, `sub-engine`, `sub-hp`, `sub-top-speed`, `sub-0_to_60`, `sub-tourque`, `sub-weight`, `sub-model-desc`, `sub-production-start-price`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11])

I modified that to this and and removed the sub-model-id because that is the primary key here is the code excluding my database login info.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
//Get's Varaiables
$form = $_POST;
$sub_name = $form[ 'car-sub-name' ];
$engine = $form[ 'engine' ];
$hp = $form[ 'hp' ];
$topspeed = $form[ 'top-speed' ];
$zeroto = $form[ '0to60' ];
$tourqe = $form[ 'tourqe' ];
$weight = $form[ 'weight' ];
$desc = $form[ 'desc'];
$msrp = $form[ 'msrp' ];
$mname = $form[ 'mname' ];

// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `car-subclass-desc`(`car-model`, `sub-model-name`, `sub-engine`, `sub-hp`, `sub-top-speed`, `sub-0_to_60`, `sub-tourque`, `sub-weight`, `sub-model-desc`, `sub-production-start-price`) VALUES (:mname,:smname,:engine,:hp,:topspeed,:zeroto,:tourqe,:weight,:desc,:msrp)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':smname'=>$sub_name,':engine'=>$engine,':hp'=>$hp,':topspeed'=>$topspeed,':zeroto'=>$zeroto,':tourqe'=>$tourqe,':weight'=>$weight,':desc'=>$desc,':msrp'=>$msrp,':mname'=>$mname));
```

Comment: So... what's the actual problem? Are you getting an error? What does $q->errorInfo() say?

Comment: The problem is that it won't show up in the database. When I echoed $q->errorInfo() it said "Array" @rjdown

Comment: Yea, don't echo it. var_dump it.

Comment: @rjdown Alright did that and it told me the problem. Thanks I am pretty new to this type of stuff and knowing all of the things to debug!

Comment: Also adding backticks to `\`table_names\`` and `\`column_names\`` is always good practise.

Comment: @Zanderwar my SQL code was straight from what PHPmyAdmin gave me.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin uses `shell_exec()` I believe. It will work until you run across a reserved name and it doesn't give you a suitable error and drives you insane until you figure it out that it was a reserved name and yeah.. now you know :)

Comment: Not that it matters since you got help on your specific problem, but phpMyAdmin shows backticks everywhere I can see (I just tested a bunch of places). How exactly did you get phpMyAdmin to generate this non-backticked code?

Comment: If you're subtracting one thing from another, use minus ('-'). Otherwise don't.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I just went to the SQL Tab and then clicked insert and it made the code for me.

Comment: @user3518071 what phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch 3.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch aswell !!

```
$form = $_POST;  
$sub_name = $form[ 'car-sub-name' ];  
$engine = $form[ 'engine' ];  
$hp = $form[ 'hp' ];  
$topspeed = $form[ 'top-speed' ];  
$zeroto = $form[ '0to60' ];  
$tourqe = $form[ 'tourqe' ];  
$weight = $form[ 'weight' ];  
$desc = $form[ 'desc'];  
$msrp = $form[ 'msrp' ];  
$mname = $form[ 'mname' ];  

try{

// query  
$sql = "INSERT INTO car-subclass-desc(car-model, sub-model-name, sub-engine,  
 sub-hp, sub-top-speed, sub-0_to_60, sub-tourque, sub-weight, sub-model-desc,  
 sub-production-start-price) VALUES (:mname,:smname,:engine,:hp,:topspeed,:zeroto,:tourqe,:weight,:desc,:msrp)";  
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
$conn>beginTransaction();  
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));  
$stmt->bindParam(':mname', $mname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);// fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':smname', $smname, PDO::PARAM_INT);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':engine', $engine, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':hp', $hp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':topspeed', $topspeed, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255); // fix your parameters values here   
$stmt->bindParam(':zeroto', $zeroto, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':tourqe', $tourqe, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':desc', $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':desc', $desc, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->bindParam(':msrp', $msrp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);  // fix your parameters values here  
$stmt->execute();  
$conn->commit();  
$stmt = null;  

}catch (Exception $e)   
        {     
            echo "error occured : " .$e;  
            $stmt = null;  
            $conn->rollback();  
        }
```